# how to put script in the tradingview advanced widget

Tags: tradingview-api

I want to put script ( https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/ ) in the tradingview advanced widget. And i understand that i use the studies property to add it to the chart

```
const widget = new TradingView.widget(
{
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_a0ff0",
  "studies": [
      "MAExp@tv-basicstudies",
      "how to include https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/ script ?"
  ],
}
```

);

the code above is tradingview advanced widget code to add indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

> **I'd like to add a custom pine script to the widget.**
>
> It is not possible to add pine scripts to widgets at this time. You
> can publish an idea with your script and embed it.

[Paste a published idea/script on your website using an embed code](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000482588-how-do-i-share-a-published-idea-script/)